# Windows command to get CPU Usage by PID of a process?

Tags: windows, winapi, cmd

I need to get CPU Usage of any process by it's process ID through Windows and MAC command prompt. If possible, get the exact % of usage by the PID.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For those who are giving negative votes to this question : I have done enough googling before raising the question. I have not got any desired solution. Can you please write down the exact windows command before clicking to the down-arrow?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, you can go through [TASKLIST](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx) and [WMIC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx).

And on MAC, [TOP](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/top.1.html) should work.

Comment: I have already gone through these two links but yet to get any way to find my requirement out. Can you please share the exact command to get my desired result?
For MAC, TOP will work. Concern is Windows.

Comment: See, if you can get this:: http://answers.splunk.com/answers/5431/identify-which-process-is-chewing-up-cpu-on-windows

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. It is giving so many information but CPU Usage.